# Security Filtering GPO

Tags: security, group-policy

I have a domain, let's called it `internal.domain.com`, which has 36 business units (separated by `OUs`). I want a policy to map a drive for the business, which is filtered by being a member of a security group (as we use location based file servers, not business orientated file servers).

Now, let's say the shares are `\\bus1-fs\data` and `\\bus2-fs` as an example. Because both business are *technically* unique, both shares have unique security groups mandating who can access the share.

Under login, I know I can run a `ps1` or `batch` script using the `net use` command to map the drive (or the inbuilt drive option in GPO), that's not an issue. The issue is I lack the skill to pull data from Active Directory to scale a single script to use the `IF` command (or similar) to lookup a users memberships and map the folder as such.

As far as I am aware the Folder Redirection GPO actually allows multiple security groups to point data to a different UNC path natively (without need for a script) - if there is a method to run a similar GPO to run certain scripts, that's ideal - I.E I do not want to make 36 unique GPOs that apply on login to map a drive, I want a single GPO to perform this.

To ensure this is easy to follow, the following paths are mapped under a security group *explicitly* - meaning I would need to replicate this GPO again.

[image: My Mapped Drives]

Now I know this can be achieved with some form of scripting (such as VBScript with LDAP) however I am looking for a simple method wherein users (such as myself) are capable of viewing and editing the script/GPO frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Item-Level targeting

[Item-level targeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733022(v=ws.11).aspx) is a feature of Group Policy Preference settings, including the Drive Maps GPP. It exposes a large number of criteria to determine if a *specific* drive map should be applied, including membership in a Security Group:

[image]

As a result, you can have a **single** group policy object that contains all of the possible drive map GPP items required by your organization. Item-level targeting is applied to each drive map preference item separately; drives are mapped when the required criteria are met and skipped when they are not met.